# Fastest screen sharing on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, 14.04, screen

Have you come across a smooth and high screen quality alernative to TeamViewr or screen sharing via Google Hangout? On long sessions it becomes very tiresome as there is so much lag so the image is very jerky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On long sessions it becomes very tiresome as there is so much lag so the image is very jerky.

That has less to do with Ubuntu software and more with the quality of the connection and the hardware (your videocard(driver) will be crucial for a perfect experience).

I use Teamviewer and Remina on a daily basis and can not say it is jerky or laggy. The images are smooth and pleasant to read. Only thing that lags is when I copy/paste text from my session into the remote one. That takes 2, 3 seconds to pick up and the text is showing slower on the screen than I can type (including the many backspaces to correct typos).

- [Here is a list of 7 RD clients](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/7-of-the-best-linux-remote-desktop-clients-716346/2). It includes a rating system wheren NoMachine NX Client gets an 8 out of 10 and Remina a 10 out of 10. The score explicitly notes "speed" as a winning factor:

> The winner, by some distance, was Remmina. Performance was exemplary, but that's not the full story. **It had the best feedback and responsiveness of any client, and if you didn't know better, the remote desktop might have been a normal-speed local machine.**
>
> **More than the performance** though, this client had the best mix of features, and a sensible and well thought-out interface. Although it did split into multiple windows, the controls are always accessible.
>
> As well as discovering clients on the network, it has a good way of storing connections, which would still work well if you had to deal with lots of desktops. Support for NX makes this an all-round winner.

Comment: Both Remmina and nomachine LOOK local only to me...am I right?

Comment: Nope. Well remmina at least can do rdp and vnc. Never used NMNX myself.

Comment: Well, both machines I am trying to connect are behind NAT.

Comment: But that should make it a router issue(?)

Comment: Well, there routers are locked by the ISP...cannot set port forwarding. I was hoping NoMachine can bypass it like TeamViewer does